# Bound of the Complex Expression

Tags: inequality

Here, $x$, $y$ and $\alpha$ are all complex numbers such that $|x|<\epsilon$ and $|y|<\epsilon$. Now what would be upper bound of the following expression:

$|\frac{\alpha+y}{x y - \alpha}|$?

Is it something like $|\frac{\alpha+y}{x y - \alpha}|<\frac{\alpha+\epsilon}{\epsilon^2-\alpha}$

Please correct me.

Aim: I aim to find out bound of $|\alpha|$ such that $|\frac{\alpha+y}{x y - \alpha}|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using triangular inequality, for $|\alpha| > \epsilon^2$,
$$\left| \frac{\alpha + y}{xy - \alpha} \right| \le \frac{|\alpha|+|y|}{|\alpha| - |xy|}< \frac{|\alpha| + \epsilon}{|\alpha| - \epsilon^2}$$

Also $$\frac{|\alpha| + \epsilon}{|\alpha| - \epsilon^2} < \epsilon \iff |\alpha|+\epsilon < \epsilon (|\alpha|- \epsilon^2) \implies |\alpha| < \frac{\epsilon + \epsilon^3}{\epsilon-1}$$

so you have the desired result if $ 1 < \epsilon^2 < |\alpha| < \dfrac{\epsilon + \epsilon^3}{\epsilon-1}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.